# Sync exactly one Google tasks list with a Windows desktop todo application

Tags: task-manager

I am looking for any Windows desktop application which I can use to sync *exactly one* task list in my Google Tasks? I do not want to sync all my lists.

My reasoning is that I´ll have job tasks in a specific Google Tasks list, and that it may be helpful to have access to those from home/phone as well. But I don´t want to sync my other lists that contain personal stuff to my work computer, I want to keep it strictly for work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists no such application to date.